# Cannot find Spell Check in Windows 8.1 Mail, NotePad, WordPad, or anything

Tags: windows-8.1, spell-check, windows-mail

I am a novice Windows 8.1 user. I bought a new Windows machine last week and I cannot find any spell check function in Windows Mail, NotePad, WordPad, or anything. In Windows 8.1, I went to PC & Devices >> Typing >> Spelling and confirmed that "Autocorrect misspelled words" and "Highlight misspeclled words" are both on. Could anyone help me? I'd appreciate it!

Comment: have you tried to look for MsSpellChackingFacility.exe

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What does MsSpellChackingFacility.exe do? I read this page:
http://www.solvusoft.com/en/files/error-virus-removal/exe/windows/microsoft/windows-8-consumer-preview-iso-images/msspellcheckingfacility-exe/
http://processchecker.com/file/MsSpellCheckingFacility.exe.html
Sorry I am a novice Windows user...

Comment: I dont have 8.1 but in win 8 this will work http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/13128-spell-checking-turn-off-windows-8-a.html